# Android , ProgressBar setVisibility while loading array inside OnClickListener

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I am trying to view ProgressBar of Spinner style while loading array after button is clicked,
The problem is :  when OnClickListener is runing all the GUI is freezing and the setVisibility command Not working until the memory loading finish.

I tryd to use runOnUiThread  or invalidate the gui and nothing is working |:

Please Help ?

```
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);  // <-- the spinner progressBar

            loadPhoneMembers();  // <-- memory loading progress 

            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(CreateFrom.this,CreateSendListFromPhoneContacts.class);      
            startActivity(intent);


        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should move your loadPhoneMembers() method to a new thread since it is a time consuming process that is blocking the UI thread. For example, you could create a class that extends `AsyncTask` and move this code to the `doInBackground()` method of this class. Here is the documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Note that you can not make changes to the user interface from a background thread